# Using a Smarty variable inside the assign statement for another variable

Tags: php, smarty

Smarty 3, PHP 5.6, Windows Server 2012, IIS10

The following code

```
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->assign("skin", "default");
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->assign("basePath", "/cart/");
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->assign("cssFiles", "{$basePath}{$skin}/product-page.css");
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->assign("cssFiles", "{eval $basePath}{eval $skin}/product-page.css");
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->assign("cssFiles", "{eval var=$basePath}{eval var=$skin}/product-page.css");
```

gives the following output

```
Smarty_Variable Object
(
    [value] => /product-page.css
    [nocache] => 
)
Smarty_Variable Object
(
    [value] => {eval }{eval }/product-page.css
    [nocache] => 
)
Smarty_Variable Object
(
    [value] => {eval var=}{eval var=}/product-page.css
    [nocache] => 
)
```

The goal is this:

```
Smarty_Variable Object
(
    [value] => /cart/default/product-page.css
    [nocache] => 
)
```

I've been all over the docs and been searching Google for an hour. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's been long enough that I'm surprised no one's answered, so, with the idea that the fastest way to find information on the internet is to say something incorrect, I'm going to answer my own question with what I used as my answer, and hope I'm wrong and will be corrected within minutes.

Answer: what you're trying to do isn't possible. You have to get the values out of the Smarty template variables into PHP variables, and then plug them back in, like so:

```
$bp = $GLOBALS["smarty"]->tpl_vars['basePath'];
$sk = $GLOBALS["smarty"]->tpl_vars['skin'];
$GLOBALS["smarty"]->append("cssFiles", $bp . "/" . $sk . "/product-page.css");
```